# Delphi: How to use line breaks in a ini file?

Tags: delphi

Is it possible to have line breaks in an ini file using Delphi?

I have a string value that I'd like to use, but it needs to have the ability for line breaks.  I don't need any other formatting of the text.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's been a while since I did Delphi, but I think you can't directly include linefeeds - a line is a line.

But as Örjan says, you can include characters in your string that can be interpreted by your program as line breaks.

I doubt that "\n" is automatically treated specially in any way in a .ini file, but you could include some other rarely used character, such as the pipe (|) or tilde (~) and just let your app translate that to a line break.

Comment: I've used #7 to replace #13#10 when saving and convert it back when reading.  It's certainly a character that won't occur naturally. :)

Comment: Like Bruce, I use the 'CRLF' string to replace the actual #13#10 when I write to the INI file. When I read, I replace back CRLF with #13#10.

Answer (score 9):

It's up to you to figure out a method to encode the line break.

Depending on the use you want to do, and the strategy you want to apply to decode it.

I use **url encoding**. This way I can cover a much broader range of possible values. There are many URL Decode implementations available.

Or you may follow Orjan suggestion. Or invent your own.

Comment: Which URL Encoding function do you use?

Comment: I use my own, dated back from the times of Turbo Pascal.

Answer (score 3):

I also need this when a value is stored in a TStringList. 
To solve this issue I have used TStringList.DelimitedText property, instead of TStringList.Text:

Define the Delimiter:

```
Items.StrictDelimiter:= True;
Items.Delimiter:= ';';
```

Save:

```
IniFile.WriteString('Session', 'Key', Items.DelimitedText);
```

Load:

```
Items.DelimitedText:= IniFile.ReadString('Session', 'Key', '');
```

Comment: Be careful. There is a bug in the Delphi 7 implementation of delimitedText that always use the blank character #32 as a delimiter. I don't know if it has been fixed in more recent versions. Test extensively.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up PA. I don't have to bother about that, I don't use Delphi 7 since Delphi 2007 was released.

Comment: @PA: It isn't a bug - it is intended, but often undesirable behaviour. Later versions of Delphi (2006+) added the "StrictDelimiter" property to avoid this.

Comment: @PA: ...and it definitely won't get "fixed" since that would break backward-compatibility.