# Ini Files - Read Multi Lines?

Tags: delphi, ini

I am aware that Ini Files are meant for single lines of information, needless to say I am trying to read/write multi lines to and from the Ini - without much success (I always seem to do things the hard way!)

Lets say my Ini File when saved, looks like this:

```
[richardmarx] 
Filenames=hazard
children of the night
right here waiting
```

Suppose the Ini File is built dynamically (ie, the richardmarx and the Filenames are not know, but unique - they could literally be anything).

How would I be able to read the Ini File?

In this example then, how could I put richardmarx into a TEdit, and the Filenames associated with richardmarx section into a memo?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Ini files are fine for many things, but I'd say that multi-line text is a step too far. I'd prefer to use a more structured format like XML or YAML or JSON.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delphi: How to use line breaks in a ini file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715393/delphi-how-to-use-line-breaks-in-a-ini-file)

Comment: similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702647/reading-inifile-to-stringlist-problem-spaces-problem

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Do not store multi-line strings into an INI file to begin with.  Escape the line breaks, like @RobertFrank suggested. I would not use an asterik for that, though, as that is a valid text character. I would use something like this instead:

```
[richardmarx] 
Filenames=hazard%nchildren of the night%nright here waiting
```

You can then read the string and replace the `%n` sequences with the value of the `sLineBreak` global variable.  If you needed to store an actual `%` character, escape it as `%%`, eg:

```
[sales] 
value=Sale! 50%% off%nat Macy's
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted?  It's getting really annoying that people downvote without explaining themselves.

Comment: I was hoping that his Filenames were all parsed legal filenames, in which case * wouldn't appear. But, your solution is safer.  (PS Having respected you and Indy for all these years, it's a thrill to be part of a proposed solution with you. No kidding!)

Comment: Why would you need to escape anything? My edit shows that you would get `Filenames=Value1#13Value2#13Value3`, and wouldn't the `#13` serve the same purpose?

Comment: It is the same concept. Raw line breaks should not be stored as-is but in an encoded format of some kind instead. `#13` serves the same purpose as `%n`, as long as you can parse it out when needed.

Comment: +1, have been using this technique for ages. Comma separators for numbers and | separator for strings.

Comment: @Remy: My point was that the CR or CR/LF are already there in the data as shown by the OP. Why is any additional escaping needed? If you're going the route of using manual parsing, the line breaks provide the escape character already.

Comment: @KenWhite: The OP showed an INI with a single string value that contains raw line break character sequences in it. That is not allowed in standard INI files. What you showed is NOT raw, it is encoded. If the source data contains raw CR characters, but your editor is showing them as `#13`, then your editor is encoding them for display purposes. That is not the same thing as storing encoded sequences in the file data itself, which is what I was describing.  Encoding would be needed if you use standard APIs to read the INI file data.

Comment: @KenWhite: Manual parsing would still need to differentiate a linebreak for a single multi-line INI value from a linebreak that separates different INI values.  Encoding the linebreaks makes manual parsing easier in that regard.

Comment: @Remy, I **know** it's not a standard INI file - read the start of my answer. The OP posted a four-line text file containing what appears to be an INI-style section heading, a properly formed value (`FileNames=`), and two additional lines of text . Where do you see any *encoding* there? Copy and paste the text into the Delphi editor or Notepad, and it appears as four separate lines of text. Since there is indeed a line break (regardless of whether it's #13 or #10 or the #13#10 pair, it's already got what you're calling an "escape".

Comment: And I know you're not new to Delphi, so you know already that simply loading the above text into a `TStringList` will take care of changing the CR/LF into a single #13 character, and also separates them into individual lines in the `Strings` property. So no manual parsing to find any "escape" is needed. Adding the "escape" would require you to do so. But all this is moot - I guess we need to just agree to disagree about this one. :)

Comment: @KenWhite: *if* you parse the file manually, you have to manually differentiate what a linebreak represents and whether it belongs inside a value or as a separator. *if* if you standard APIs (`TIniFile`/`TMemIniFile` or direct Win32 profile API), linebreaks inside of values have to be encoded. That's all I was saying.

Answer (score 6):

You're not using a valid `.ini` format, so it's not going to be easy. It's much easier if you use a properly formed `.ini` file.

A valid `ini` file is of the format

```
[section]
akey=value
bkey=value
ckey=value
```

Here's a sample of reading multiple lines from an ini file. While it uses a `TListBox` instead of a `TEdit`, it should be enough to get you started.

The code below will work with an improperly formatted file as well, but you'll probably have to change the code in the `ListBox1Click` event to use `ReadSectionValues` instead and do some manual parsing for each item before displaying them; in that case, create another `TStringList` in the event handler and pass it instead of `Memo1.Lines`.

With a properly formatted `ini` file, you can use `TIniFile.ReadSection` or `TMemIniFile.ReadSections` to load all of the sections into a `TStrings` descendant, and then use `ReadSection(SectionName)` to get each section's values.

Here's an example - save this `ini` file somewhere (I've used `d:\temp\sample.ini`:

```
[A Section]
Item1=Item A1
Item2=Item A2
Item3=Item A3
Item4=Item A4

[B Section]
Item1=Item B1
Item2=Item B2
Item3=Item B3
Item4=Item B4

[C Section]
Item1=Item C1
Item2=Item C2
Item3=Item C3
Item4=Item C4
```

Here's a sample of the form's code:

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, IniFiles;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    ListBox1: TListBox;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
    procedure ListBox1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FIni: TMemIniFile;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

const
  IniName = 'd:\Temp\Sample.ini';


procedure TForm2.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  FIni.Free;
end;

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FIni := TMemIniFile.Create(IniName);
  Memo1.Lines.Clear;
  FIni.ReadSections(ListBox1.Items);
end;

procedure TForm2.ListBox1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Section: string;
begin
  if ListBox1.ItemIndex > -1 then
  begin
    Section := ListBox1.Items[ListBox1.ItemIndex];
    FIni.ReadSection(Section, Memo1.Lines);
  end;
end;

end.
```

Clicking on each section name in the `ListBox` displays the items that are in that section, as seen below:

[image: Application Screen Capture]

EDIT: OK. I got curious to see how it would work with the ini file content you posted in your question.

So I made the following change:

- Copied and pasted your sample ini content verbatim as a new section to the end of the `Sample.ini` I created above.

Ran the code, and clicked the new `richardmarx` item. Here's what I got:

[image: Sample image 2]

Obviously, that wouldn't work. So I made the following additional changes:

- Changed the `ListBox1Click` event to use `FIni.ReadSectionValues` instead of `ReadSection`.
- Ran the modified application, and clicked on the `C Section` item to see how it displayed, and then the new `richardmarx` item to see how it displayed. The results are as follows:

[image: Image with C Section selected][image: Image with richardmarx selected]

Comment: Interested to know what would happen when there are more keys with multiple lines in the section, or even just multiple keys with one of them having multiple lines (and that one being either the first, the last or somewhere in the middle).

Comment: Sure. But that's an exercise best left to the person who chose to use the malformed ini file, isn't it? :) I've given a good start - the rest is up to @Craig.

Answer (score 4):

*Pre-process the .ini file!* Change all line-breaks between ] and [ to some character that will never appear in a filename (like asterisk).   Then use TInifile to access the file you just preprocessed, changing the asterisks back to line breaks after you retrieve the strings. (Use [StringReplace](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.StringReplace/))

It's a little more complicated than that if you have more than one identifier in a section. In that case, you could use the equals sign as a flag that the preceding line break should not be removed. Maybe you read the file from the end towards the beginning.

You could even create a descendant of TIniFile that did the astrerisk-to-linebreak change for you.

No, this is certainly not an elegant solution.  But, sometimes brute force like this works if you're stuck! The other solutions here are probably better, but thought I'd share this anyway in case it gives you a direction to think about heading...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, chr(0) might be hard to visualize if someone opens the file in notepad. chr(9) (= tab) might be a better choice then.

Comment: @LURD this answer proposes use of the special character internal to the process, not of disk

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, aah saw that too late. Still, putting chr(0) in strings gives me cold chills in the spine :)

Answer (score 2):

Using any *TStrings* descendent object you can just use the ***CommaText*** property to read and write all the lines as a single string.

```
MyStrings.CommaText := IniFile.ReadString('Section', 'Ident');
```

and

```
IniFile.WriteString('Section', 'Ident', MyStrings.CommaText);
```

*CommaText* is smart enough to handle lines containing commas by automatically embracing them in quotes.

Comment: I'm looking back at the original question's sample data, and I don't see even a single comma. Are you seeing something I'm not?

Answer (score 2):

this code show you how to write and read multi lines with INI file

```
procedure TForm1.SaveButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IniFile.WriteString('Name', 'FirtName', FirstName.Text);
  IniFile.WriteString('Name', 'LastName', LastName.Text);
  IniFile.WriteInteger('Alpha Blend', 'Alpha Blend Value', Form1.AlphaBlendValue);
//Here start save Memo Lines
  LinesCount := AboutMemo.Lines.Count;
  IniFile.WriteInteger('About', 'Lines Count', LinesCount);
  for I := 0 to LinesCount-1 do
  IniFile.WriteString('About', 'About'+IntToStr(I), AboutMemo.Lines[i]);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin;
  GetCurrentDir;
  IniFile := TIniFile.Create(ChangeFileExt(Application.ExeName, '.ini'));
  FirstName.Text := IniFile.ReadString('Name', 'FirstName', '');
  LastName.Text := IniFile.ReadString('Name', 'LastName', '');
  Form1.AlphaBlendValue := IniFile.ReadInteger('Alpha Blend', 'Alpha Blend Value', 255);
//Here Start Read Memo Lins From INI File
  LinesCount := IniFile.ReadInteger('About', 'Lines Count', 0);
  for I := 0 to LinesCount-1 do
  AboutMemo.Lines.Insert(I, IniFile.ReadString('About', 'About'+IntToStr(I), ''));
end;
end.
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted something similar, to include the body of an automated email in the ini file.
But I also wanted blank lines in the body.  Here is part of the ini file

```
[EmailBody]
This is the weekly Survey Status notification email.
.
It lists Survey Reports that may need some attention.
.
The purpose of this information is to improve conduct-of-operations in our tracking, 
recordkeeping, and maintenance of Survey Reports.  This report will also enable 
us to identify any changes made to electronic Surveys following the normal QA review.
.
Please review your information weekly and determine if you need to take corrective action.
```

Here is what I ended up doing

```
var
  Config: TMemIniFile;
  sl: TStringList;
...
  sl := TStringList.Create;
  Config.ReadSectionValues('EmailBody', sl);
  for i := 0 to sl.Count - 1 do
    if sl[i] = '.' then
      sl[i] := '';
```

Answer (score 1):

@Ken White

**FIni.ReadSectionValues** get full string after same key, like "key=value".

In *.ini* like

```
[B Section]
Item1=Item B1
Item B2
Item B3
Item4=Item B4
```

and after

```
FIni.ReadSectionValues('B Section',Memo1.Lines);
```

**Memo1.Lines** will be **{'Item1=Item B1', 'Item4=Item B4'}**

---

Unfortunately, we can't read values directly, without any key.
But in fact, it's not too difficult:

```
procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var i:longint;
strtemp: TStringList;
begin
  FIni := TMemIniFile.Create(IniName);
  Memo1.Lines.Clear;
  Fini.ReadSection('B Section',strtemp);
for i:=0 to strtemp.Count-1 do
  Memo1.Items.Add(Fini.ReadString('B Section',strtemp[i],''));
end;
```

**Memo1.Lines** would be **{'Item B1', 'Item B4'}**

Upper method will read all values in section, without keys.
How to read not-keyed values - I don't know (if at all it possible in *.ini*).
As a solution for huge non-format *.ini*, just numerate all strings - read file like text file, find needed section and add same count index like a key, schematically(!):

```
FileString[i]:=inttostr(i)+'='+FileString[i];
```

If need mixed format, will require more complicated parser.

P.S. Sorry for my english, I'm not strong in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ReadSections](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/IniFiles.TIniFile.ReadSections) method to get all the section names in ini file.

And perhaps you can use [TMemIniFile's](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/IniFiles.TMemIniFile) [ReadSectionValues](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE2/en/IniFiles.TMemIniFile.ReadSectionValues) method to read "multiline values" (ie to read whole section into stringlist). If that doesn't work then perhaps you could use [GetStrings](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE2/en/IniFiles.TMemIniFile.GetStrings) to get the content of the ini file and parse it "semy manually" - IIRC it returns you a stringlist with section names where each item's object holds another stringlist with section data.