# Delphi 7 - Save to a Specific .INI Files Name

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I modified the [MasterMan82's TIniFile code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17631509) to read and write multi values from & to TEdit/TComboBox and TMemo.

Forgive my vague questions, my english is not good.

So, what I mean is:

I have a couple of .INI files, A.ini, B.ini, C.ini ....and so on. I just store A.ini as a variable in the code. It is not possible to put all the file names in the code.

When I opened A.ini, make some changes, click SAVE to save any changes made, and success!. Of course, because A.ini has been defined in the code.

However, when I open the file B.ini or C.ini or D.ini...making the change, and save, reopen the file, but all changes in the file is gone or not saved, of course, because only the A.ini was defined in the code.

So, my goal is how to keep or records all file revisions ?

Below is the code.

```
......

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, 
  Graphics, Controls, Forms, IniFiles, Dialogs;

......

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
   I, LinesCount: Integer;
   Read         : TIniFile;
begin
   Read  := TINIFile.Create(ExtractFilePath(Application.EXEName)+ 'A.ini');
// Read  := TIniFile.Create(ChangeFileExt(Application.Exename,'A.ini'));
  Try
   Proxy.Text   := Read.ReadString('SETTING','Proxy','');
   Port.Text    := Read.ReadString('SETTING','Port','');
   Route.Checked:= Read.ReadBool('SETTING','Route',False);
   // TO READ MEMO LINES
   LinesCount := Read.ReadInteger('MEMO', 'Lines Count', 0);
   for I := 0 to LinesCount-1 do
   Memo1.Lines.Insert(I, Read.ReadString('MEMO', 'Item'+IntToStr(I), ''));
  Finally
   Read.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.SaveClick(Sender: TObject);
var
   I, LinesCount: Integer;
   ToSave       : TIniFile;
begin
  ToSave := TINIFile.Create(ExtractFilePath(Application.EXEName)+ 'A.ini');
  Try
   ToSave.WriteString('SETTING','Proxy',Proxy.Text);
   ToSave.WriteString('SETTING','Port',Port.Text);
   ToSave.WriteBool('SETTING','Route',Route.Checked);
   // TO SAVE MEMO LINES
   LinesCount := Memo1.Lines.Count;
   ToSave.WriteInteger('MEMO', 'Lines Count', LinesCount);
   for I := 0 to LinesCount-1 do
   ToSave.WriteString('MEMO', 'Item'+IntToStr(I), Memo1.Lines[I]);
  Finally
   ToSave.Free;
 end;
end;

procedure TForm1.OpenClick(Sender: TObject);
var
   I, LinesCount: Integer;
   OpenFile     : TIniFile;
begin    
   OpenDialog.Filter:='Ini File (.ini)|*.ini';
  if OpenDialog.Execute then begin
   Memo1.Clear;
   OpenFile := TINIFile.Create(OpenDialog.FileName);
  Try
   Proxy.Text   := OpenFile.ReadString('SETTING','Proxy','');
   Port.Text    := OpenFile.ReadString('SETTING','Port','');
   Route.Checked:= OpenFile.ReadBool('SETTING','Route',False);
   // TO READ MEMO LINES
   LinesCount   := OpenFile.ReadInteger('MEMO', 'Lines Count', 0);
   for I := 0 to LinesCount-1 do
   Memo1.Lines.Insert(I, OpenFile.ReadString('MEMO', 'Item'+IntToStr(I), ''));
  Finally
   OpenFile.Free;
  end;
 end;
end;
```

Comment: What you're really asking doesn't even have anything to do with INI Files. It has to do with loading a file which was saved previously. You should step back, ignore the whole INI files (as it's irrelevant to your question), and just think about making your app remember where a file is located.

Comment: I've read this three times, and to me, it's not clear what is being asked.

Comment: One thing I must immediately point out is the use of redundant code. You have the same block of code used in both the constructor and a button click handler. You should learn to use procedures and functions to handle this sort of thing - encapsulating this logic once and re-using it. Encapsulating and self-containing things like this are important to achieve the goal you're looking for.

Comment: I've no idea what the question is. I think if you can find a way to ask the question clearly then you'll get an answer.

Comment: In `OpenClick`, you sign to the variable `Open`, but you never use it afterward. Instead, you use `Read`, and then you destroy it. Is it possible that that bug is making it hard to understand the rest of your problem?

Comment: You always open a file named `A`. If you don't want always to open the same file, why are you always opening the same file?! Is your question, "how do I remember a value from one run to another?" In which case Rob has answered already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open an ini file, store the filename in a variable as explained in many comments.

Example, (`FCurrentIniFilename: String;` is a private variable in TForm1):

In the `FormCreate` event:

```
FCurrentIniFilename := ExtractFilePath(Application.EXEName)+ 'A.ini';
Read  := TINIFile.Create(FCurrentIniFilename);
...
```

In the OpenFile event:

```
if OpenDialog.Execute then begin
  FCurrentIniFilename := OpenDialog.Filename;
  Open := TINIFile.Create(FCurrentIniFileName);
  try
    ...
  finally
    Open.Free;
  end;
end;
```

When you are saving the information:

```
ToSave := TINIFile.Create(FCurrentIniFilename);
```

Comment: Thank you. But i got error when the SAVE button is clicked, [see here](http://s4.postimg.org/6vb3rvlpp/err.png)

Comment: It looks as though you never assign a value to `FCurrentIniFilename`. You must learn how to debug your code. Put a breakpoint at parts of code you have trouble with and check why these errors happens.

Comment: I rolled back the last edit, please don't change the question. `FCurrentIniFilename` must be global in scope as explained in my answer.

Comment: Oh, my mistakes. It is working now thanks!. By the way, I've updated my post with a question that I forgot to ask it.. Can you teach me solutions, please ? Thank you so much, LU RD!.

Comment: That is another question. The Q&A format here at SO is that one question at a time is answered. If you have a new question, open a new question instead of editing this one.

Comment: @Fabian I respectfully suggest that *you* look more closely at your own code, and the comments and answers. You seem oblivious to much of what has been said to you. For instance, you still use a variable named `Read` in `OpenClick` that is not defined. My guess is that you posted fake code, that is code other than the code you have in front of you. In my opinion you need to slow down and try a little harder to understand your own code.

Comment: Thank you, David, for your suggestions. I'll look more closely @ my code.

Answer (score 1):

You're expecting there to be magic where none exists. If you want to save to the same file you opened, then store the chosen name in a variable when you open it, and then use that variable when you save, too.

Likewise, if you want to remember the name from one run to the next, then you need to store the name in persistent storage (like the registry or an INI file), and then read that name when your program starts next time.

It's not difficult to get what you've requested, but you'll have to write some code for it.

Comment: Why is b.ini stored in the variable? You opened a.ini. Use variables to keep track of whatever you need.

Comment: Your explanation was the result of my code above. Whereas my problem is: ...Let's say i have **a.ini** and **b.ini**. When i open **a.ini** and click save button, after editing it, then this file is not changed, because the **b.ini** stored in a variable. So how to write the correct variables so that any file name that is being used still can be saved ?. Thank you.

Comment: @Fabian I read your comment many times over and over, and all I can understand is that you now have 2 different INI file instances using the same variable, and when you create B.ini it replaces the A.ini variable in code which is not visible in your question? Why aren't you using two different variables in that case? Your code doesn't even show any indication of re-using variables, as your comment suggests.

Comment: **a.ini** and **b.ini** are just simply examples, because I have more than two **.ini** files. if I create a variable with a specific file name, e.g. **a.ini**, then when i using **b.ini**, then it changes could not be saved. so my goal is that the code can save any .ini file that is currently in use.

Comment: Of course my explanation is the result of your code above. What else would you expect me to use? I can only see what you show me. Anyway, I understand that you have two files on your disk. You open a.ini, make some changes on your form, and save. What I don't understand is why saving would affect b.ini at all. You didn't open it. When you open a.ini, store `'a.ini'` in a string variable. When you save, use that variable to know which file to open. Where do you run into trouble with this plan?