# Delphi - automatically Loads the Last Used of .INI File

Tags: delphi, ini

I need your help.

Let's say that I have three .INI files: **Default.ini**, **Stack.ini**, and **Overflow.ini**. I just store **Default.ini** as a variable in the code. This setting of course, it will automatically load the file **Default.ini** every time the application is run. It's not possible to put all the file names in the code, of course.

So my problem is, when I re-run the application, I want the .ini file that loads automatically is the last recently used of .ini file.

How to do that ?

Thank you for your help and your help would be greatly appreciated!

Below is the most actual important part of my codes [based on  [MasterMan82's TIniFile code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17631509)].

```
......

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, 
  Graphics, Controls, Forms, IniFiles, Dialogs;

......

private
  FCurrentIniFilename: String;

......

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
   I, LinesCount: Integer;
   Read         : TIniFile;
begin
   FCurrentIniFilename := ExtractFilePath(Application.EXEName)+ 'Default.ini';
   Read := TINIFile.Create(FCurrentIniFilename);
  Try
   Proxy.Text   := Read.ReadString('SETTING','Proxy','');
   Port.Text    := Read.ReadString('SETTING','Port','');
   Route.Checked:= Read.ReadBool('SETTING','Route',False);
   // TO READ MEMO LINES
   LinesCount := Read.ReadInteger('MEMO', 'Lines Count', 0);
   for I := 0 to LinesCount-1 do
   Memo1.Lines.Insert(I, Read.ReadString('MEMO', 'Item'+IntToStr(I), ''));
  Finally
   Read.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.SaveClick(Sender: TObject);
var
   I, LinesCount: Integer;
   ToSave       : TIniFile;
begin
   ToSave := TINIFile.Create(FCurrentIniFilename);
  Try
   ToSave.WriteString('SETTING','Proxy',Proxy.Text);
   ToSave.WriteString('SETTING','Port',Port.Text);
   ToSave.WriteBool('SETTING','Route',Route.Checked);
   // TO SAVE MEMO LINES
   LinesCount := Memo1.Lines.Count;
   ToSave.WriteInteger('MEMO', 'Lines Count', LinesCount);
   for I := 0 to LinesCount-1 do
   ToSave.WriteString('MEMO', 'Item'+IntToStr(I), Memo1.Lines[I]);
  Finally
   ToSave.Free;
 end;
end;

procedure TForm1.OpenClick(Sender: TObject);
var
   I, LinesCount: Integer;
   OpenFile     : TIniFile;
begin    
   if OpenDialog.Execute then begin
    FCurrentIniFilename := OpenDialog.Filename;
    Open := TINIFile.Create(FCurrentIniFileName);
  Try
   Proxy.Text   := OpenFile.ReadString('SETTING','Proxy','');
   Port.Text    := OpenFile.ReadString('SETTING','Port','');
   Route.Checked:= OpenFile.ReadBool('SETTING','Route',False);
   // TO READ MEMO LINES
   LinesCount   := OpenFile.ReadInteger('MEMO', 'Lines Count', 0);
   for I := 0 to LinesCount-1 do
   Memo1.Lines.Insert(I, OpenFile.ReadString('MEMO', 'Item'+IntToStr(I), ''));
  Finally
   OpenFile.Free;
  end;
 end;
end;
```

Comment: Have another INI file where you store which config file you loaded as last. Or start using registry as many people did years ago. With that you could have *all in one place* instead of many files (config profiles you could have in separate registry keys).